# Digital signature informations in .docx with C#

Tags: c#, digital-signature, docx

I'm working with .docx files in my application via [DocX](http://docx.codeplex.com/) library which I use to edit some parts of document and parse templates. My problem is when client digitally sign document, I don't know how to get informations about signature. I need to check who signed document.

I think that DocX library doesn't provide me with that informations, or I couldn't figure it out where to find them.

Any other suggestions will be most appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've spent couple of days in research and find out that you could read document signature with: `System.IO.Packages -> PackageDigitalSignatureManager` [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.packaging.packagedigitalsignaturemanager(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
Package pkg = Package.Open(documentStream, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite);

PackageDigitalSignatureManager dsm =
                new PackageDigitalSignatureManager(pkg);
```

where doucumentStream is `MemoryStream` of your file.

Then you can check if file is digitally signed, verify that signature, or get details about that signature (who, where, why).

```
dsm.IsSigned ...
dsm.VeryfySignature() ...
dsm.Signatures ...
```